# Я сделал игру на пайтон и делаю exe файл через pyinstaller, но у меня вылазит ошибка при открытии exe

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller, exe

Я прописываю команду pyinstaller main.py --onefile -- windowed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Сторонние модули типа `pygame` там как-то отдельной настройкой прописывать нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было переустановить библиотеки коммандой `pip uninstall <библиотека>` либо удалить из папки или всю папку pip

Answer (score 1):

[Документация](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search)

> **--hidden-import MODULENAME, --hiddenimport MODULENAME**
>
> Name an import not visible in the code of the script(s). This option can be used
> multiple times.

Попробуйте:

`pyinstaller main.py --onefile --hidden-import pygame`

`pyinstaller --hidden-import=my_module my_script.py`

`pyinstaller --hidden-import=my_module,my_other_module my_script.py`

`pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import "pygame" "C:/Users/Amgarak/Desktop/main.py"`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте библиотеку nuitka.

```
pip install nuitka

python -m nuitka --windows-disable-console \
                 --windows-icon-from-ico=путь к файлу --run путь к файлу
```

> --windows-disable-console - убирает консоль
> --windows-icon-from-ico=путь к файлу - добавляет иконку
> --run путь к файлу - путь к проекту