# Вылазит ошибка при запуске exe файл на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Написал калькулятор на **Python**, используя библиотеку **Pygame**(да, я псих)). Да и подумал почему бы не сделать из него exe файл. Использовал *pyinstaller* ну и написало что все прошло успешно. Однако когда я запустил файл выдало ошибку:

```
File "calculator.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

[image: Вот скрин ошибки]

в командную строку когда компелировал файл писал:
`pyinstaller -F -w calculator.py`

так же пробывал просто через `pyinstaller -F calculator.py`
но в этом случае, заместь ошибки моемнтально открывалась и закривалась командная строка.

можно это как то решить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Я сделал игру на пайтон и делаю exe файл через pyinstaller, но у меня вылазит ошибка при открытии exe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1571537/%d0%af-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%8e-exe-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-pyinstaller-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88)